# What is the effect of temperature on titration between Iron(II) sulfate and potassium permanganate

Tags: redox, titration

I'm conducting an experiment in school, the titration of Iron(II) sulfate dissolved in H2SO4 against potassium permanganate.  In this, I am varying the temperature that the analyte is heated to and finding the titration value.  I'm finding a general upward trend as increase temperature, but I can't find the theoretical values for this or the way to calculate them.

Any assistance on how to calculate the theoretical titer required at different temperatures would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide more details about the experiment, like used concentrations, temperatures and titration volumes. // One of reasons, that can be difficult to quantize theoretically, is thermal decomposition of the permanganate, leading to higher spent volumes.

Comment: Temperature has no effect on the stoichiometry of chemical reactions. Only the kinetics of the reaction is modified by the temperature. And Poutnik is right in stating that permanganate is not very stable at high temperature : it gets thermally decomposed when hot.

Comment: Users Poutnik and Maurice make excellent points. However I'll raise a different point. The Nernst equation is temperature dependent. So it is possible that changing the temperature could effect if a reaction occurs. Also for a reaction like copper being dissolved with nitric acid,  the nitric acid can undergo two different reductions. So changing the temperature would effect the "overall stoichiometry" as the ratio between the two reactions changes.